# Bounding $\int_{\infty}^{\infty}|g(s)v^3k(v)|dv$ where $k$ is a second-order kernel

Tags: integration, probability-theory

> Suppose $k$ is a nonnegative, bounded real-valued function that satisfies
>   $$
> \int_{-\infty}^\infty k(v)dv=1,\quad k(v)=k(-v),\quad \int_{-\infty}^\infty k^2(v)dv<\infty,\quad\kappa_2\equiv\int_{-\infty}^\infty v^2k(v)dv<\infty.
> $$
>   Suppose that $g$ is continuous. How can one show that
>   $$
> \int_{-\infty}^\infty|g(s)v^3k(v)|dv\leq C\int_{-\infty}^\infty|v^3k(v)|dv
> $$
>   for some positive constant $C$? Here, $s\in[x,x+hv]$ for some fixed $x$ and some positive constant $h$. (In particular, $s$ depends on $v$.) Perhaps to ensure that $C$ exists, we need to assume $|h|$ is sufficiently small but I'm not sure. **Edit**: please assume $g$ is bounded in a neighborhood around $x$ is you find it necessary.

**Context**: this is in the setting of kernel density estimation and $k$ is a kernel function. The claim above is given without proof on page 11 of Li and Racine (2007).

Following an earlier question I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1075745/178464), I consider $\int_{-M}^M|g(s)v^3k(v)|dv$ for some fixed positive $M$. Then by the continuity of $g$, $g(s)$ is bounded on $s\in[x-hM,x+hM]$ so we can bound $\int_{-M}^M|g(s)v^3k(v)|dv$. But I don't know what to do about the tail contribution. Thank you for your help.